# Move mulitple rows in excel to another excel workbook

Tags: excel

I need help in creating a macro that will move my completed items from one excel spreadsheet to another workbook called completed items and delete them once transferred over. I am new to the macros and vba code. 
Example: A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I have header titles and every row in column "I" that says "complete" needs to be moved by row to the Completed workbook in the same order at the beginning of the spreadsheet always. Once it is transferred over the rows would need to be deleted from the Summary workbook. I hope this makes sense.

Thank You.

Comment: What have you tried? What did your search yield? Which code snippets do you think are a good start? -- Oh, or do you expect us to do ALL your work for you?

Comment: no I don't want all the work done for me. I just need to know if anyone has a code. The code I used was

Comment: Sub SummarizeSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rw As Range, cDest As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set cDest = Worksheets("Sales").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Sheets("Sales").Activate
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Sales" Then
            For Each rw in ws.Range("A2:K45").Rows
                If rw.Cells(1,"K").Value = "completed" Then
                    cDest.Resize(1, rw.Columns.Count).Value = rw.Value
                    Set cDest = sDest.Offset(1, 0)
                End If
            Next rw
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub

Comment: but I does not work.

Comment: Please edit your question and add additional info there. Post a comment when you've updated your question. You may want to take a look at the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to use this site.

Comment: Disregard this post. The person "teylyn" answering to this post is really rude and if that is the way you give input and/or help, don't. Either ways, thank you for taking your time to reply, it was all good for nothing.

Comment: I'm sorry you can't be bothered to learn how this site works. Godspeed!